# How to access fully fledged version of Google Apps Scripts?

Tags: scripting

I've just created a lengthy script creation prompt for Googles Gemini AI I based on its instructions but what it didn't tell me is that I also need to have access to the fully fledged version of Google Apps script to be able to access the Google Drive API and run the script completely.

I'm a novice with all of this and I'm just wondering if I need to be a Google developer to be able to do this or have access to Google's paid workspace services?  Is this option only available for Google Enterprise users?

When I attempt to access any of the menu items Gemini is prompting me to use to enable the Google Drive API, those menu items do not exist in my interface/tool bar. The AI tells me that this is because I'm using the web app. As far as I was concerned, there is only a web app? I'm a bit confused and wondering how to proceed with my project.

TIA for any advice offered.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.